# WiFi disconnects in doze mode

Tags: wi-fi, 8.1-oreo, project-fi

Nexus 5x and Pixel with project fi. No antivirus installed.
OS 8.1.0

Regularly puts me on LTE connection both at home and in the office.

How do I force WiFi to always connect to known networks rather than surprising me every time that I just watched a video and used tons of data?

Is this related to the [removal of Wi-Fi sleep options](https://www.androidpolice.com/2017/10/25/android-8-1-feature-spotlight-keep-wi-fi-sleep-option-removed-pixel-2/)? And what "Sleep options are not relevant any more." means that the [relevant commit message](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Settings/+/2fca2ebddfca4e704d8676bec15bd2b6750ee933) ([via reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Android/comments/78flj1/google_inexplicably_removed_the_keep_wifi_on/dotk16l/)) says?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Customer service explained me that my Project Fi SIM card is expected to kick me off from free Wi-Fi whenever it decides that the LTE connection is stronger. He said the customer should every single time manually put himself to airplane mode as a remedy. Complete bullshit esp. given that fact that it loses Wi-Fi in sleep even if data is off so waking the phone would not give me any connection, until I would force a reconnect by opening settings.

Finally, a device update from March 5 fixed it, so now my Wi-Fi stays on.